# How to use static Resource images in static Resource javascript

Tags: javascript, static-resources

How to use **static Resource images** in **static Resource java script**,

```
 <img class="canceluploadicon" src="EasyResources.zip/images/closeIcon.png" alt="cancel" width="30"></a></div>');
  //$j('#progressBox').append('<input type="text" value="" ><div id="fileSize">Size: '+size+' KB</div></div><br/><br/>');
```

at src how can i call static Resource image

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JavaScript global in your Visualforce (where `URLFOR` etc works):

```
<script>
var closeIconUrl = "{!URLFOR($Resource.EasyResources, 'images/closeIcon.png')}";
</script>
```

and then use jQuery in some later JavaScript that is included in the page from a static resource to set that value as the image `src`:

```
$j('img.canceluploadicon').attr('src', closeIconUrl);
```

A related technique, not requiring a change in the Visualforce, is to hard code the URL format that is output by `URLFOR` and use the current time to ensure that the latest version of the static resource is used (though this will likely stop that resource being cached by the browser);

```
$j('img.canceluploadicon').attr(
        'src',
        '/resource/' + Date.now() + '/EasyResources/images/closeIcon.png'
        );
```